# User privilege considerations when executing terminal code in Objective-C

Tags: macos, cocoa, terminal, privileges

I am writing an application that will update the firmware on a piece of particular hardware. This application will therefore be run on a large number of different OSX systems around the world, so it'd like to make sure I get it right first time.

The application will simply run a series of terminal commands quietly, in the background.

What I'd like to know is: what user privilege/access issues should I be considering when writing an application that will be run on a number of different systems?
It's not a very specific question, I know, but I'm trying to gauge what sort of issues I should be expecting.

Comment: Is `root` access required to update the firmware on your device?

Comment: I'm not sure as I haven't seen the code yet. If root access is required, what additional aspects should I consider?

Comment: Yep. USB hardware. 
Will need to input the following command:
sudo cp libusb-1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that reads this, I needed to consider root access, for which i wrote a helper tool that has admin rights:
http://www.bdunagan.com/2008/11/23/sudo-nstasks-with-mac-os-xs-security-framework/